# recursion code should go infinitely?

Tags: python

So, i am trying to learn python and i come across this code to demonstrate recursion in python. Now , I know c++ and I thought this code should create an infinte loop but it doesn't. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated. This is an program to sort a list by insertion sort.

```
def InsertionSort(seq):
    isort(seq, len(seq))


def isort(seq, k):  # Sort slice seq[0:k]
    if k > 1:
        isort(seq, k - 1) #1
        insert(seq, k - 1) #2


def insert(seq, k):  # Insert seq[k] into sorted seq[0:k-1]
    pos = k
    while pos > 0 and seq[pos] < seq[pos - 1]:
        (seq[pos], seq[pos - 1]) = (seq[pos - 1], seq[pos])
        pos = pos - 1
```

Shouldn't the compiler got to #1 and again call isort and thus return in a infinite loop and never go to #2. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: no because after a while k <= 1

Comment: Haven't you forgotten about the `if k>1` line? isort will call itself until `k=1`, after that the return sequence would follow

Comment: No, but in a case of loop of length > 1, wouldn't isort just keep calling itself, without going to the next line of insert which performs an insertion sort? And if k = 1, wouldn't that mean the insertion sort has ended?

Comment: No. Each time it calls itself, k is one lower. Eventually it will reach 1 and the loop will terminate.

Comment: They call it *interpreter* in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will terminate as the function is calld with `k-1`, meaning that the condition `k>1` will eventually evaluate to `False`.

Imagine recursion is like a continually growing tree and a squirrel is the interpreter. When the `isort()` function is called, the tree branches off and the squirrel runs to the end of that branch. However, the tree uses has a finite supply of nutrients (`k`) each time, and a bit is used (`k-1`) each time it grows a new branch. The tree will stop branching off when it runs out of nutrients (which is the `k>1` condition). When the tree stops growing, the squirrel will reach the end of the last branch and get the nut (`return` value/ next line(s) of code). The squirrel will now run back to the roots (the code (if any) after the call to the recursive function) by going back through the branches (leaving each recursion depth). When the squirrel arrives back at the roots, the program is finished.

(Hope this analogy helps :) )

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, but wouldn't the interpreter, never go to line #2 as it keeps calling, isort until the condition proves false and terminate. Wouldn't the insertion sort never happen? ( sorry if I'm sounding redundant(and possibly stupid))

Comment: @Divakar Say `k=3` at the start, it will call `isort(seq, 3)` to start, then `isort(seq, 2)`, then `isort(seq, 1)`, then `insert(seq, 1)`, then `insert(seq, 2)`. You're right in that `insert` wont be called until all `isort`s are finished, but because `k` is being decremented each time, eventually no more additional calls will be made.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a bunch. One last question @NickA, where does the increment of k take place in the code. Thank you for helping in furthering my understanding.

Comment: @Divakar It doesn't `k` never gets incremented in the code you've provided